# Woocommerce cart problems and errors

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I am getting following error after trying to delete

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/melkypie/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/melkypie/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

This is the code around pluggable.php line 1196
`if ( ! $location )
        return false;

```
$location = wp_sanitize_redirect($location);

if ( !$is_IIS && PHP_SAPI != 'cgi-fcgi' )
    status_header($status); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups

header("Location: $location", true, $status);//Line 1196

return true;`
```

Also when I am not logged in with my admin account I cannot add products to my cart. It shows that the product has successfuly been added to the cart but when I go to there. It shows that the cart is empty.
I have checked the woocommerce system status and it is showing that everything is fine there
Can anyone help me with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some blanks spaces in the core files like functions.php that might have caused an error in your case. Make sure to delete them.

Refer to [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-override-cannot-modify-header-information) Post for further clarification.